# How to implement a DragOver Function in Angular CDK?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, draggable, angular-cdk

I have already tried different packages. Unfortunately I can't even make my element draggable with most of them.

With CDK the draggable works fine. But I want to trigger an action as soon as I drag the image A to the image B. Unfortunately this does not work. I last tried to test it with the DropList, so please don't be confused about my code.

what i need is really just a function like:
html image B: <img (dragOver)="dragOver($event)">

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragEnd, CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-care',
  templateUrl: './care.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./care.component.css']
})
export class CareComponent implements OnInit {
public imgStyle = 0.8;
 breedExternal: Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
  constructor() { this.imgStyle = 0.8; }
  ngOnInit(): void {  }

onDragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
        event.source._dragRef.reset();
}

 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
   console.log("drop");
  }


  dragOver(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  console.log("dragover works");
}



}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="tab_care" >
        <div class="col-2">
<img id="brush" src="A" class="draggable" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary="#tab_care"   (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)" #brush>
</div>
<div class="col-10">
<img src="B" id="dropzone" cdkDropList cdkDragHandle
         [style.opacity]="imgStyle" 
         (cdkDropListEnter)="dragOver($event)"
  dragOverClass="drop-over-active">
        </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: Are you sure it's `cdkDropListEnter` ? Because it seems to be `cdkDropListEntered` here https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I had "cdkDropListEntered" before but it did not work either, so I tried many things, maybe too many

Comment: Does your `(onDragEnded)` is working? Have you try adding `cdkDropListGroup` to your first div `<div class="row" id="tab_care" >` ?

Comment: Yes this function works perfectly.

I finally found the solution: This whole draggable code does not work on image, so I put a span around it. It finally worked now.

Thank you for your support. I really needed the cdkDropListGroup too!

My final question is: Is there an opportunity to get the id of the dragged div in typescript? I want to use different divs and then do different functions (via switch & case) in my dragOver function.

Comment: I think you can find it in `$event` but if not, you can use Angular Templating and pass the `div` to your function like this `<div #myDraggableDiv  (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event, myDraggableDiv)"... />`

Comment: THANK YOU :) Yes I had the same thought with $event, but I needed many tries. Now it finally detects the right id.
If anyone reads this and still needs help, try: `event.item.element.nativeElement.id`